# Converting a IQueryable IEnumerable entity to a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have this query below and it returns a

```
IQueryable<IEnumerable<YogaSpaceEvent>>
```

but I want tit to return a List of YogaSpaceEvents

```
var listYogaEvents = dbContext.YogaProfiles.Select(i => i.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(j => j.EventStatus == YogaSpaceEventStatus.Active));
```

How do I get it to return a

```
List<YogaSpaceEvents>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Select` to  `SelectMany` then call `ToList` like this:

```
List<YogaSpaceEvents> result = 
       dbContext.YogaProfiles
                .SelectMany(i => i.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(j => 
                          j.EventStatus == YogaSpaceEventStatus.Active)).ToList();
```

This will collapse (flatten) all the nested `IEnumerable<YogaSpaceEvent>` and then accumulate the elements into a `List` instance.